# the meaning of "by" below

Tags: meaning

"Turkey’s Islamist president is the first civilian with control over his country’s military – and you can **tell by the results**."

in the sentence, does "by the results" mean "with" or something else if it does so, may ı change "by" with "with" ?

Comment: 'By' is what may be termed an 'ablative' expression. 'By means of' cannot be altered to 'together with' - it is a different kind of verb operation.

Answer (score 2):

No, "by" and "with" are not interchangeable here.

This is meaning #2 of [by](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by)

> 2. often with verbal noun Indicating the means of achieving something.
>      [Oxford dictionaries]

You could replace "by" with "from" here without changing the meaning, but I believe "by" is more idiomatic.

Comment: It's got an implicit *by **looking at** the results*, I think.